# MVC ActionLink to another website with ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In MVC you are able to create a List page that fetches everything from the Model/DB.

At the bottom of said lists there are links which look like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.id }) |
```

Which brings us to my question. I was wondering how one would make an ActionLink similar to that but it redirects to another website?

So I.e. if the link was http://something.com/Folder/Index?showId=x

Where X is the ID of the item clicked through my website.

Would it look something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "http://something.com/Folder/Index?showId=", new { id = item.id }) |
```

Comment: Why not use `<a></a>`?

Comment: Would I be able to somehow get the { id = item.id } at the end of the link within the <a> tag somehow? @MikeDebela

Comment: I think you need `<a href='@string.Format("http://something.com/Folder/Index?showId={0}", item.id)'>Edit</a>`

Comment: Much appreciated friend, never thought it could be done that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href='http://something.com/Folder/Index?showId=@item.id'>Edit</a>
```